# How to control objects with 3Dconnexion joypad?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, 3d-mouse

For a project I created two hands in Blender. Now I would like to control these with an external device. I was trying to use Leap Motion Controller but I realized that there's a problem of compatibility with the python used. For this reason, I'm trying to use a 3D connexion joypad but with this, I read that I can only control just the camera. Is this true? How can I switch from view navigation to object transforms control?

Comment: As of Blender 2.59 they should be fully supported: https://www.3dconnexion.de/nc/company/press-room/pressdetail/browse/3/article/3dconnexion-3d-mice-help-digital-artists-create-dazzling-3d-designs-in-blender-259.html?tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=88&cHash=e61016efb3